# Environment Texture glitching out

Tags: world

[image: glitched out]

My Image Texture is glitching out and does not appear normal. It looks fine in renders, though.

[image]

Comment: Looks okay when I open it.

Comment: Probably just a problem with my computer. Ugh. Should I try rebooting or whatever?

Comment: Not sure. I think I would start with redoing the node setup. if that didn't work, restarting Blender. If that didn't work, trying the texture in a new blend. If it works in the new blend, then somethings wrong with the other one.